# how do i get my old games on my new account?

Tags: steam

If I purchased Counterstrike 1.6 and Condition Zero on my old PC (with my old Steam account), how do I get my game on my new Steam account and new PC?

I have lost or forgotten my CD key.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use your old account anymore?

Comment: I wouldn't think this is possible, I'm afraid.

Comment: Assuming you didn't realise that you can just log into your old Steam account on your new PC, I recommend using your old Steam account on the new PC. If you cannot do that for some reason, I recommend adding it to your post.

Comment: Use your old steam account or if there is a special reason you dont want to do that, just take your new account and add the old one with family share

Answer (score 8):

You don't need a new account for a new PC, in case you've somehow been convinced that you do. On the new PC, sign in with the old account and all your games will be available. You won't be able to play games on both at once but, unless you're sharing your account, that won't be an issue.

Another option, if you still have both PCs and already have two accounts, is to enable [Family Sharing](http://store.steampowered.com/promotion/familysharing). This allows accounts to access games from each other. There are a lot of restrictions, however, and it would need you to log both accounts in at once to use old games from the new account.

Unfortunately, Valve do not typically merge accounts or transfer activated games to prevent people selling accounts or games. If you can prove you own both accounts and can explain why you made two which now need merging (you haven't here), you might get lucky. [Contact Steam Support here](https://support.steampowered.com/) but expect to wait a while.

Answer (score 1):

Contact steam support, provide proof that you own the account, get ready with a very good answer as to why you can't just use the old account anymore.

Maybe you'll get lucky!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you could transfer activated (non-gift) games between two accounts. Your best shot is to try recovering the old account.